# Renaming a .html page in website templates?

Tags: html, css, templates, bootstrap-5, dashboard

I bought a free dashboard website template from the internet and I'm trying to implement it according to my own website.

I'm trying to create a navbar and I want to open the relevant page when clicked.

I created a new file by completely copying the contents of the html file named datatable.html in the template and called it parcel_list.html.

but the styling is not applied
[it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTUHI.png)

how can i solve this problem?

I have no idea what to do

[datatable.html looks like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jdt5p.png)

[folder structer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Se7uK.png)

[folder structer all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PhIs.png)

[datatable.html styling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBw9J.png)

Comment: You must have missed to add css (styling properties to the new .html page)

Comment: but I copied the datatable.html page exactly. don't the style files there also apply in parcel.list.html ?

Comment: _"don't the style files there also apply in parcel.list.html ?"_ - if they can still be _found_ to begin with. Most likely they are embedded using a relative URL, and if the URL of the  content rendered via `parcel_list.html` you are looking at now, has a different folder "depth" that the one you used to view the original, the resulting absolute stylesheet URLs will be wrong now.

Comment: So what exactly should I look for or fix now?

Comment: this is my first template task sorry for my ignorance :(

Comment: can you list your file structure or the style linking structure here

Comment: no your folders structure in code editor

Comment: I added new now, How not?

Comment: no issues here. something wrong in your datatable.html it may be linked with index.html . can you show the datatable.html file first part head section/ styles section

Comment: if you can link the whole template itself i can test it out in real and check it for you

Comment: of course, i would be very happy   https://github.com/puikinsh/Adminator-admin-dashboard

Comment: have you been able to check?

Answer (score 0):

```
I have looked in to the template
it is a node js project with sass styling
that is why the styling not working
you must have nodejs installed on your system to run nodejs projects locally
then in prject terminal 'npm install' then 'npm run dev' 
(this will open the project in right way with styles and all)
```

documentation is given here:
https://github.com/puikinsh/Adminator-admin-dashboard#getting-started

Comment: that's right, I also installed nodejs and did npm install as well. The project works fine in local, there is no problem, but I copy the existing .html files and it causes problems when I rename them.

Comment: actually I will cry :'(